Spring JPA Data bidirectionality doesn't work
Working on some sort of social media where u can post events in your city. Want to add opportunity to like Events.
Event entity:
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private String date;

    private String time;

    private String location;

    private String image;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Like> likes = new HashSet<>();

}

Like entity:
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="like_of_events")
public class Like {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="event_id")
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User appUser;

}

The problem is that I cant access any likes from Event instance. It just has empty Set. However, Like entity have Event instance nested and I can easily access it. I use PostgresSQL db
Was testing it smth like this ():
public  ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable Long eventId){
    var event = eventService.getEventById(eventId).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Event is not found")
    );
    System.out.println(event.getLikes());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}


Logs look smth like this:
Hibernate: 
    select
        e1_0.id,
        e1_0.date,
        e1_0.description,
        e1_0.image,
        e1_0.location,
        e1_0.time,
        e1_0.title 
    from
        event e1_0 
    where
        e1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        l1_0.event_id,
        l1_0.id,
        a1_0.appuser_id,
        a1_0.email,
        a1_0.first_name,
        a1_0.last_name,
        a1_0.password,
        a1_0.role 
    from
        like_of_events l1_0 
    left join
        appuser a1_0 
            on a1_0.appuser_id=l1_0.user_id 
    where
        l1_0.event_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        l1_0.event_id,
        l1_0.id,
        a1_0.appuser_id,
        a1_0.email,
        a1_0.first_name,
        a1_0.last_name,
        a1_0.password,
        a1_0.role 
    from
        like_of_events l1_0 
    left join
        appuser a1_0 
            on a1_0.appuser_id=l1_0.user_id 
    where
        l1_0.event_id=?
[]

Please, could you help me to understand what's gone wrong?
I was trying to use different orm annotations, adding columns and tables namings manually. This problem causing Deletion problem - I cant delete event cuz "likes" table have reference on "event" table. And because this connection cant work properly Cascade types also wont work.
And also tried to add like to Set of likes of Event manually.
